# Pair a non-type with each type in variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

Is there any way I can have variadic pair of types? My goal is to add extra information with each type.

Something like so:

```
// non compilable code

// I want to pass an extra uint8_t with each type here.
template<template<typename EnumType, uint8_t Bitmask> typename... EnumsAndBitmasks>
void func(){
    // Unpack EnumsAndBitmasks and do something with pairs of each EnumType and it's Bitmask
}

// Call func like this
enum class Type1 : uint8_t;
enum class Type2 : uint8_t;
enum class Type3 : uint8_t;

func<<Type1,0x03>, <Type2,0x3C>, <Type3,0xC0>>();
```

The following is non-templated working code, but I want to generalize this process by providing returning struct type and each EnumType and it's bitmask as a template argument to the `unpack_from_single_byte` function.

```
enum class EnumType1 : uint8_t { first, second };
enum class EnumType2 : uint8_t { first, second, third, forth };
enum class EnumType3 : uint8_t { first, second };

struct Unpacked
{
    EnumType1 var1;
    EnumType2 var2;
    EnumType3 var3;
};

Unpacked unpack_from_single_byte(uint8_t value)
{
        return { static_cast<EnumType1>(value & 0x01), 
                 static_cast<EnumType2>(value & 0x06), 
                 static_cast<EnumType3>(value & 0x0F) };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a level of indirection. First, introduce a tag:

```
template<class T, std::uint8_t v> struct Tag {
    using Type = T;
    static constexpr std::uint8_t value = v;
};
```

And then write:

```
template<class... Tags>
void func() { /* ... */ }

func<Tag<Type1, 0x03>, Tag<Type2, 0x3C>, Tag<Type3, 0xC0>>();
```

You can extract `T` and `v` through members `Type` and `value`. For example:

```
template<class... Tags>
void func() {
    std::tuple<typename Tags::Type...> tuple;
    std::uint8_t values[] = {Tags::value...};
}
```

**Edit.** If I got your generalization correctly, you might want something like this:

```
template<class... Tags>
std::tuple<typename Tags::Type...> unpack_from_single_byte(std::uint8_t value) {
    return std::tuple<typename Tags::Type...>{
        static_cast<typename Tags::Type>(Tags::value & value)...};
}

... = unpack_from_single_byte<
    Tag<Type1, 0x03>, Tag<Type2, 0x3C>, Tag<Type3, 0xC0>>(0x20);
```

This function returns a `std::tuple` (generalization of `Unpacked`) with each member equal to `Tag::value & value`, where `value` is the function parameter.

Alternative syntax without `Tag`s might be:

```
template<class... Enums, typename... Bitmasks>
std::tuple<Enums...> unpack_from_single_byte(std::uint8_t value, Bitmasks... bitmasks) {
    static_assert(sizeof...(Enums) == sizeof...(Bitmasks));
    return std::tuple<Enums...>{static_cast<Enums>(value & bitmasks)...};
}

... = unpack_from_single_byte<Type1, Type2, Type3>(0x20, 0x03, 0x3C, 0xC0);
```

Comment: Perfect, that's what i had in mind, is there any way to eliminate Tag struct in call site?

Comment: @ashtum, if you want to keep enums and uints together as template parameters, I guess not. If you relax this requirement, you have some options. For example, you can move uints into function parameters and write something like this: `unpack_from_single_byte<Type1, Type2, Type3>(value, 0x03, 0x3C, 0xC0)` and then check that the number of enums and uints match.